# Why are Loaders bad in Android

Tags: android

I have read a couple of tweets and comments here and there about Loaders being bad and using them is a good way to "shoot yourself in the face". Also **commonsguy** announced that he will discontinue any work on his library : **Loaderex**. **Commonsguy** also said "Loaders are a failed abstraction."

I'm obviously missing something here and I would like to learn more and understand why are Loaders bad and why should one avoid them.

Note: I have created an Android application (perhaps of middle complexity) where I use Loaders and haven't had any troubles with Loaders. That's why it's puzzling me.

I would also like to know about other better ***alternatives*** to Loaders. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> why are Loaders bad and why should one avoid them

You will note that this is not what I said. I said that loaders are a failed abstraction. There's a difference.

A general recommendation, when trying to create a framework for significant reuse, is to design and create three discrete implementations of the framework. If your framework can support three different approaches, the design is probably flexible enough to handle future implementations.

The `Loader` framework, at the end of the day, is designed around one implementation: `CursorLoader`. Period. There are no other concrete implementations of `Loader` in the SDK. In particular, the `Loader` framework has a contract that requires that implementations of `Loader` be able to deliver updated results automatically. While this is a lovely contract from the standpoint of *users* of the `Loader` framework, it makes things difficult for those who might create *implementations* of the `Loader` framework.

I attempted to create two separate implementations of the `Loader` framework, for SQLite and `SharedPreferences` (three if you count SQLCipher for Android separately). The SQLite one sucks, because the only way to do the automatic-reload stuff is for the `Loader` to know what needs to be reloaded, which is clunky. The `SharedPreferences` one used to work, but it was pointed out that nowadays `onLoadFinished()` will not be called if the object representing the results (the `Cursor` for a `CursorLoader`, `SharedPreferences` for `SharedPreferencesLoader`) is the same object as before. That breaks `SharedPreferencesLoader`, since the `SharedPreferences` object is updated *in situ* when preferences are changed.

After writing my `Loader` implementations and using them for a bit, I concluded that they weren't worth it. I'd rather load stuff myself asynchronously using `AsyncTask` or `IntentService` and use a message bus (Otto, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.) for notifying interested parties about changes in data. While I *could* wrap that stuff inside of `Loader`, I am unconvinced that it would solve enough problems to be worth the effort.

Now, if you are using a `ContentProvider` and wish to use `CursorLoader`, that's fine. It may have its own issues, but at least it's supposed to work.

With respect to the CWAC-LoaderEx library, I am discontinuing it because:

- I only have so many hours in the day, and so as part of the great AAR-ification of the CWAC libraries, I am deciding which libraries are worth the effort to maintain
- I do not use CWAC-LoaderEx personally, outside of a couple of book examples
- CWAC-LoaderEx is dependent upon too much internal implementation of `Loader` for me to be comfortable that I will be able to keep it working over the long haul (see `SharedPreferencesLoader`)

CWAC-LoaderEx isn't going anywhere, but I just will not be putting more time into it. If somebody with a maintained/extended fork contacts me, I'll be happy to link to their fork from the project README.

> I would also like to know about other better alternatives to Loaders

All a `Loader` does is asynchronously load content, re-load that content upon a detected change in the content, and retain said content across a configuration change. A retained model (or headless) fragment can do the same thing, in concert with an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As a new developer, this area of Android puzzled me the most. I never expected to have to seek out solutions like LoaderEx in the first place, but implementing a full blown ContentProvider is a huge hassle and you often question if the view is worth the climb. For me, LoaderEx is absolutely perfect, though because I use IntentServices, I need to get creative with refreshing the loader upon DB changes. So be it, as you say, I only have so many hours in the day. Thanks for LoaderEx, for me, it is the best solution that is reasonable to implement!

Comment: ContentProvider/Loader synergy is really nice if you get used to work with them. Just use the content provider Uri in the loader and the refreshing will be done for you. If you don't have a complex data structure you can use https://github.com/Triple-T/simpleprovider to remove most of the boilerplate code involved in creating a content provider.

Comment: Can you provide some more resources on the issue with the SharedPreferences loader and onLoadFinished() not being called?

Comment: @TylerPfaff: I have nothing more than what I wrote in the answer.